# Using a non-class new statement inside an enum creating?

Tags: java

In Java, is it alright to do the following?

```
public enum MyEnum {

    FirstVariable(new nonEnumClass()),
    SecondVariable(new nonEnumClass())

    MyEnum(nonEnumClass class) {

    }
}
```

I'm unsure if I should do that, or if I shouldn't.

I'm sorry if the question isn't clear enough, I don't know how to further clarify it.

Comment: No one will stop you. (except the compiler because you named the variable "class".)

Comment: The only thing you should care about - all published from your enum fields/objects should be unmodifiable.

Comment: I mean, for example, if my class will always be that object, is that alright no use the new? It seems wrong

Comment: In that case, maybe it *should* be an eNum, even if a different one. An eNum is a way to represent a singleton. But perhaps you should expand your question to describe what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: Let me example it with a string,

I want for example do:
First(new String("a") ),

Is that ok?

Comment: @Kerooker: There's no point in doing it with a string; you might as well do `First("a")`.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to example it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine!

However, you'll have a compiler error here:

```
MyEnum(nonEnumClass class)
```

`class` is a keyword in Java, you can't name a parameter that.

`MyEnum(nonEnumClass myClass)` is fine though.

Also, typically class names in Java have every word capitalized (`NonEnumClass`), though that doesn't really matter.

Comment: But using the 'new' in the enum body is ok?

Comment: Yup! That's totally fine.